# Can I specify Azure Blob File as Data Source in the OleDB connection string?

Tags: .net, azure-blob-storage, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbexception

I am very new to OleDB stuff. I am just making changes to someone else's .NET project, and they're using OleDB when creating a data report file.

Currently, a local data file is being passed to the OleDB as a data source (part of the OleDB connection string). So the connection string looks something like this: `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\SomeFolder\SomeFile;..."`

However, I need to have the `Data Source` be a file I have in my **Azure Blob**. What I tried is setting the connection string's `Data Source` to something like: `https://azure-storageacc-name.blob.core.windows.net/blobcontainername/myfile.xlsx`, but when I try to pass a connection string having this Data Source, I get an error when I try to open **oleDBConnection**:
`System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Failure creating file.'`

```
connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open() //<-- WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS;
```

Does somebody know if it is possible to pass a connection string to oleDB where Data Source is an Azure Blob source? If yes, how would I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, we can't use **Azure Blob** has a Data Source of **OleDB**.  As per [Ms-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/ole-db-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver16) we can use Excel workbook and Database in  **OleDB**.

By default, if we want to make use of Azure blob, we need to have access to the blob with either SAS URL or Connection String. In **OleDB** we cannot access in a data source.

Configure the data source to connect **OleDB** which meet the provider prerequisites.

For the above selected provider ensure that creds are secured, and the connection is created and retained during the runtime.

Refer [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/53aebe83-ba68-4252-8041-cffc0619fa54/store-alegacy-database-in-blob-container-and-read-using-oledb?forum=visualfoxprogeneral) discussion for the related issue.